# Wordpress for Intranet portal?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, joomla, intranet

I need a intranet portal for a Repair factory in which 100 Technician worked. 
The main purpose of this portal is "sharing technical information (like technical bulletins etc)".

I also create a simple website/portal with HTML,Javascript. Which is running sucessfully.

But Now we need a Blog like site in which Technician can share own experience/knowledge with other. for this requirement i tried with Joomla,wordpress, drupal etc.

firstly suggest me which platform is best? i have beginning knowledge of PHP, JavaScript and JQuery.

requirement:

1. Technician can post a article within one or more defined categaries.(like model,level of information,Electrical or mechnical etc.)
2. After submitting articles, it sent to the Technical Specialist or Technical Editor for approval.
3. after approved it is published to Blog with ranting,commenting option.

Which theme,plug-in is suitable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Plone (http://plone.org/), I think it fits perfectly for your needs.

> Plone lets non-technical people create
>   and maintain information for a public
>   website or an intranet using only a
>   web browser. Plone is easy to
>   understand and use — allowing users to
>   be productive in just half an
>   hour — yet offers a wealth of
>   community-developed add-ons and
>   extensibility to keep meeting your
>   needs for years to come. "

Answer (score 0):

For those looking these days and who want / need WordPress you can use Woffice (https://woffice.io/) or Thrive. Both have all these features.